# Writing to the /var/tmp directory in C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ofstream

I am using Ubuntu and I am trying to create a new file in the /var/tmp directory in c++ but for some reason it is not creating the file. Also, how long do files last in this folder usually?

Here is what I have:

```
string defaultPath = "/var/tmp/a.txt";
ofstream ouputFile(defaultPath);
```

I think it is something with "/var/tmp/" I am not sure because I am not that familiar with linux operating systems. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Should be no problem, unless /var/tmp doesn't exist, or has permissions that don't allow you to create files there. Are you checking the error state of the ofstream?

Comment: You can call the method "good()" on the `ofstream` after constructing it; if it returns `false`, then the file couldn't be opened properly.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this question is unrelated to C++, you should check if user, which runs the program has permissions to create a file in /var/tmp:

```
touch /var/tmp/a.txt
```

Then check if file is created there. If not check permissions on /var/tmp and fix them by `chmod` or choose directory where the user has write permissions.